# Sort a list with a specific way

Tags: php, list, sorting, numbers

I have a list of number in my database and wanna list them like this:

```
1
11
111
11101
11101001
11101002
11102
11102001
11102002
11102003
11102004
11103
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are the rules for listing?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Comment: If you want to sort them as strings, cast them to a string. If you have some other rules, you have to specify them.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I really don't know how to do this, I already try read the [PHP sort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) with no luck to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to sort the items as strings. This way, "11101002" comes before "11102". 
The parameter `SORT_STRING` will achieve that when [sorting an array with `sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php):

> sort($myarray, SORT_STRING);

You will need to populate an array with the data from your database.

Other option, possibly less costly, is to sort them directly when querying the DB, by using [ORDER BY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by).

Answer (score 2):

What you wanna do is to treat your numbers like strings.
You can `CAST` or `CONVERT` your numbers to strings :

```
ORDER BY CAST(my_numeric_column AS CHAR(50))
```

Comment: "I have a list of number in my database". Anyways, every sort on database field should be done in the query. Just way more faster.

Comment: whithout php code but still a better solution. thank u!